# convert SQL server query to snowflake , i need help in calling local variable using javascript

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**# sql server query:#**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCurrencyExchange]
        (@ExchngType NVARCHAR(30), 
         @InCurrMode NVARCHAR(10), 
         @OutCurMode NVARCHAR(10), 
         @InDate     DATE) 
RETURNS DECIMAL(17, 6) 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @lExchangeRate DECIMAL(17, 7); 
      DECLARE @2ExchangeRate DECIMAL(17, 7); 
      DECLARE @3ExchangeRate DECIMAL(17, 7); 
      DECLARE @4ExchangeRate DECIMAL(17, 7); 
       
      DECLARE @currdate NVARCHAR(30); 
      IF ISNULL(@ExchngType,'') = '' -- Default use Balance Sheet Exchnage rate
        SET @ExchngType = 'Income Statement';

     IF  ( @InCurrMode = @OutCurMode AND @InCurrMode IS NOT NULL AND @OutCurMode IS NOT NULL )
        RETURN 1;

      IF @InDate = '' 
         SET @currdate = getDate(); 
      Else 
        SET @currdate = @InDate;

      SELECT TOP 1 @lExchangeRate =  ExchangeRate 
      FROM   (SELECT a.ExchangeRate ExchangeRate
                                        , Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.ValidFrom DESC) Id 
                        FROM   [STG].[stgFXRateOut] a
                        WHERE  a.FromCurrency =  @InCurrMode 
                        AND a.ToCurrency =  @OutCurMode
                        AND a.ValidFrom <= @currdate
                        AND a.ExchangeRatetype = @ExchngType
                        ) f 
      WHERE id = 1; 

      IF @lExchangeRate IS NOT NULL 
        RETURN @lExchangeRate; 


      IF @lExchangeRate IS NULL 
        BEGIN 
            SELECT TOP 1 @lExchangeRate =  ExchangeRate 
            FROM   (SELECT a.ExchangeRate ExchangeRate
                            , Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.ValidFrom DESC) Id 
                            FROM   [STG].[stgFXRateOut] a
                            WHERE  a.FromCurrency =  @OutCurMode
                            AND a.ToCurrency =  @InCurrMode 
                            AND a.ValidFrom <= @currdate
                            AND a.ExchangeRatetype = @ExchngType
                            ) f 
            WHERE id = 1; 
        END 

      IF @lExchangeRate IS NOT NULL 
        RETURN ( 1 / @lExchangeRate ); 

      IF @lExchangeRate IS NULL 
        BEGIN 
             SELECT TOP 1 @lExchangeRate =  ExchangeRate 
                FROM   (SELECT a.ExchangeRate ExchangeRate
                                        , Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.ValidFrom DESC) Id 
                        FROM   [STG].[stgFXRateOut] a
                        WHERE  a.FromCurrency =  @InCurrMode 
                        AND a.ToCurrency =  'USD'
                        AND a.ValidFrom <= @currdate
                        AND a.ExchangeRatetype = @ExchngType
                        ) f 
            WHERE id = 1; 

      IF @lExchangeRate IS NULL 
            SELECT TOP 1 @lExchangeRate = 1 / (CASE WHEN exchangerate = 0 THEN 1 ELSE exchangerate END)
            FROM   (SELECT a.ExchangeRate ExchangeRate
                                        , Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.ValidFrom DESC) Id 
                        FROM   [STG].[stgFXRateOut] a
                        WHERE  a.FromCurrency =  'USD'
                        AND a.ToCurrency =  @InCurrMode 
                        AND a.ValidFrom <= @currdate
                        AND a.ExchangeRatetype = @ExchngType
                        ) f 
            WHERE id = 1; 


            SELECT TOP 1 @2ExchangeRate = exchangerate 
                    FROM   (SELECT a.ExchangeRate ExchangeRate, 
                                    Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.ValidFrom DESC) Id 
                        FROM   [STG].[stgFXRateOut] a
                        WHERE  a.FromCurrency =  @OutCurMode 
                        AND a.ToCurrency =  'USD'
                        AND a.ValidFrom <= @currdate
                        AND a.ExchangeRatetype = @ExchngType
                        ) f 
            WHERE id = 1; 

      IF @2ExchangeRate IS NULL 
            SELECT TOP 1 @2ExchangeRate = 1 / (CASE WHEN exchangerate = 0 THEN 1 ELSE exchangerate END) 
            FROM   (SELECT a.ExchangeRate ExchangeRate, 
                                Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.ValidFrom DESC) Id 
                        FROM   [STG].[stgFXRateOut] a
                        WHERE  a.FromCurrency =  'USD'
                        AND a.ToCurrency =  @OutCurMode 
                        AND a.ValidFrom <= @currdate
                        AND a.ExchangeRatetype = @ExchngType
                        ) f 
                WHERE id = 1; 

            SELECT @3ExchangeRate = ( @lExchangeRate / @2ExchangeRate ); 
        END 

      RETURN Isnull(@3ExchangeRate, 0); 


END
```

convert this into snowflake , need help on this on?

i tried but i was unsuccessful

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "fn_FncurrencyExchange"("ExchngType" NVARCHAR(30),"InCurrMode" NVARCHAR(10),"OutCurMode" NVARCHAR(10),"InDate" DATE) 
RETURNS NUMBER(17,6)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
COMMENT='Create Date: 2022-11-25  Author: Performalytic Team '
AS '
var lExchangeRate =p1;
var 2ExchangeRate =p2;
var 3ExchangeRate =p3;
var 4ExchangeRate =p4; 
var currdate =p5;

IF (ISNULL(ExchngType,'') = '' )
   { ExchngType = ''Income Statement'';
   }
     
IF  ( InCurrMode = OutCurMode AND InCurrMode IS NOT NULL AND OutCurMode IS NOT NULL )
        RETURN 1;

IF InDate = '' 
   { p5 = CURRENT_DATE(); 
   }
Else 
   { p5 = InDate;
   }

   SELECT  p1 =  ExchangeRate 
      FROM  (
             SELECT a."ExchangeRate" ExchangeRate
                                     , Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a."ValidFrom" DESC) Id 
              FROM   DBO."DimFXRateOut" a
              WHERE  a."FromCurrency" =  InCurrMode 
              AND a."ToCurrency" =  OutCurMode
              AND a."ValidFrom" <= p5
              AND a."ExchangeRatetype" = ExchngType
                        ) f 
      WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1; 

IF p1 IS NOT NULL 
       RETURN p1; 
    
IF p1 IS NULL 
   BEGIN 
            SELECT  p1 =  ExchangeRate 
             FROM   (SELECT a."ExchangeRate" ExchangeRate
                            , Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a."ValidFrom" DESC) Id 
                            FROM   DBO."DimFXRateOut" a
                            WHERE  a."FromCurrency" =  OutCurMode
                            AND a."ToCurrency" =  InCurrMode 
                            AND a."ValidFrom" <= p5
                            AND a."ExchangeRatetype" = ExchngType
                            ) f 
             WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1; 
    END 

IF p1 IS NOT NULL 
        RETURN ( 1 / p1 ); 

IF p1 IS NULL 
    BEGIN 
             SELECT  p1 =  ExchangeRate 
                FROM   (SELECT a."ExchangeRate" ExchangeRate
                                        , Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a."ValidFrom" DESC) Id 
                        FROM   DBO."DimFXRateOut" a
                        WHERE  a."FromCurrency" =  InCurrMode 
                        AND a."ToCurrency" =  ''USD''
                        AND a."ValidFrom" <= p5
                        AND a."ExchangeRatetype" = ExchngType
                        ) f 
               WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1; 

 IF p1 IS NULL 
            SELECT  p1 = 1 / (CASE WHEN exchangerate = 0 THEN 1 ELSE exchangerate END)
            FROM   (SELECT a."ExchangeRate" ExchangeRate
                                        , Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a."ValidFrom" DESC) Id 
                        FROM   DBO."DimFXRateOut" a
                        WHERE  a."FromCurrency" =  ''USD''
                        AND a."ToCurrency" =  InCurrMode 
                        AND a."ValidFrom" <= p5
                        AND a."ExchangeRatetype" = ExchngType
                        ) f 
            WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1; 


            SELECT  p2 = exchangerate 
                    FROM   (SELECT a."ExchangeRate" ExchangeRate, 
                                    Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a."ValidFrom" DESC) Id 
                        FROM   DBO."DimFXRateOut" a
                        WHERE  a."FromCurrency" =  OutCurMode 
                        AND a."ToCurrency" =  ''USD''
                        AND a."ValidFrom" <= p5
                        AND a."ExchangeRatetype" = ExchngType
                        ) f 
            WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1; 
         END
      IF p2 IS NULL 
         BEGIN
            SELECT  p2 = 1 / (CASE WHEN exchangerate = 0 THEN 1 ELSE exchangerate END) 
            FROM   (SELECT a."ExchangeRate" ExchangeRate, 
                                Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a."ValidFrom" DESC) Id 
                        FROM   DBO."DimFXRateOut" a
                        WHERE  a."FromCurrency" =  ''USD''
                        AND a."ToCurrency" =  OutCurMode 
                        AND a."ValidFrom" <= p5
                        AND a."ExchangeRatetype" = ExchngType
                        ) f 
                WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1; 

            SELECT p3 = ( p1 / p2 ); 
         END 

      RETURN ISNULL(p3, 0); 

END 
  ;`;
```

Comment: In what way were you unsuccessful - it errored (what messages) or it did not give you the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You set the language to JavaScript, you started with JS commands but you try to run SQLs directly. It is also defined as UDF, in this case you can't call SQLs from JavaScript.

Do you need to create a UDF? Then check this one: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/sql/udf-sql.html

If you want conditionals etc, and run SQL directly, consider SQL scripting (but it will be a stored procedure): https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index.html

You may also want to check writing Stored Procedures in JavaScript: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-javascript.html